# Redirect logged in user to somepage on every page view?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

Is there a hook that is called everytime a logged in user requests to view any page?

Basically I want to continually redirect a logged in user to a specific page until they complete a requested action. So no matter what page they try to view, I want to be able to redirect them.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would utilize the user meta info and 'wp' hook for this. You can use a function similar to below:

```
add_action( 'wp', 'wpse69369_special_thingy' );
function wpse69369_special_thingy()
{
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && "" == get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'completioncheck', true ) )
        wp_redirect( string $location ); 
        exit;  
    }
}
```

Then when the user completes the action necessary you can use the following function:

```
add_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'completioncheck', 'yes' );
```

Info on the user meta functions I used can be found here:

[get_user_meta()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta)

[add_user_meta()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_user_meta)

Comment: This does not redirect admin dashboard pages, but that is okay for my purposes as it is only site pages that I need redirected.

Comment: @jsherk If you think there should be a line "exit; //need to use exit after wp_redirect or it may not work.", please add that as a comment, not as an edit to the answer, because you cannot know if Fender04 agrees. If he does, he can edit it himself.

Comment: I've never had to add it but if jsherk needed it I can add it. Just comment and let me know.

Comment: @cjbj @Fencer04 You are always supposed to use `exit;` with `wp_redirect()`. I would not have edited answer if it was not required. See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/